# Find and replace value between square brackets

Tags: python, python-2.7

Someone know how got something like:

```
array = ["one", "two", "three"]
str = "text123123text:[852],[456465],[1]"
```

And i want replace all between brackets to result

```
output: text123123text:'one', 'two', 'three'
```

I try by `re.sub('\[.*?\]'," ''", str)` 
and I got `output: text123123text:'', '', ''`
It is of course logical, but how create method which for each sub replace call function with index replace argument and next return text from array.

In pseudo code I imagine this that:

```
array = ["one", "two", "three"]
def abstract_function(replace_index):
    return array[replace_index]

str = "text123123text:[852],[456465],[1]"
print re.sub('\[.*?\]'," '$CALL:abstract_function$'", str)

output: text123123text:'one', 'two', 'three'
```

Exist any method to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do like this,

```
>>> stri = "text123123text:[852],[456465],[1]"
>>> array = ["one", "two", "three"]
>>> d = {i:j for i,j in zip(re.findall(r'\[[^\]]*\]', stri), array)} # create a dict with values inside square brackets as keys and array list values as values.
>>> d
{'[852]': 'one', '[456465]': 'two', '[1]': 'three'}
>>> re.sub(r'\[[^\]]*\]', lambda m: "'" + d[m.group()] + "'", stri) # replaces the key with the corresponding dict value. 
"text123123text:'one','two','three'"
```

Comment: Thanks You, Avinash Raj:)